# Hover list item space (width and height) and not text space

Tags: html, css

I want to hover the space in each rectangle changing the background color and the color, but not changing it when you hover the text in other column. Did that make sense?
Example: Hover on "About" and not "Home" or "Contact" when hovering the text.

I really don't know how to explain this well, so if you please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielcorreia/Nfnyd/) you'll see my problem.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you want.

Comment: If you move your mouse on the About rectangle on the right side, you'll see that when you hover the first letters of Contact, the Contact rectangle turns black. I want the hover area to be only the rectangle and not text. But when hovered the text changes color. Maybe it's only possible with jQuery…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modern browsers use:

```
#bighome,#bigabout,#bigcontact {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or the most compatible way is to put the #bigxxxx spans outside the a-element. So

```
<li id="contactlink"><a href="#">Contact</a><span id="bigcontact">contact</span></li>
```

(you have to specify the font-color for the spans)

Comment: With the span outside how can I use a:hover?

Comment: You could use li:hover span{} or you could use a:hover+span{}